# Accessing modules from the parent package

Tags: python, import

I am an absolute, self-learning beginner to Python. I am working with module imports.

If I can write

```
import sklearn.model_selection as skms
kf = skms.KFold()
```

, which works, why then can't I write

```
import sklearn as sk
kf = sk.model_selection.KFold()
```

This yields the error

```
module 'sklearn' has no attribute 'model_selection'
```

Can you please help me understand why?

Thanks,

Comment: `model_selection` is submodule or subfile which is not directly in module `sklearn` and you have to import it.

Comment: if you run `import sklearn` and `print( sklearn.__file__ )` then you get full path to source code - `sklearn/__init__.py` - and you will see that `model_selection` is NOT in this file but it is subfolder/submodule  `sklearn/model_selection/__init__.py`. And to load code from this subfolder you have to use `import sklearn.model_selection`. If you use only `import sklearn as sk` and later `sk.model_selection` then is searching in `model_selection` inside `sklearn/__init__.py` instead of loading `sklearn/model_selection/__init__.py`